# Release apk crashing after using proguard

Tags: java, android, sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

Have tried all most all the tricks in the bag but can't figure out what is missing. The debug build runs fine but the release build fails as soon as it starts up.

I guess, the exception - "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: invalid UTF-16 codepoint" is what is causing the crash, but then how is it working fine on a debug build ? That puzzles me.

Yes, I have gone through most of the questions here but none seems to fix my issue. Request someone with the expertise to please help here..

Here is the crash logs from adb -

02-28 04:37:53.298 11467-11467/? E/a:  E --- a --- Unexpected error in generating key

```
                                          at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(SecretKeyFactory.java:474)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:67)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:53)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:88)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                          at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:83)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:71)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:53)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:88)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:53)
02-28 04:37:53.299 11467-11467/? E/a:     at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:88)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                          at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:83)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:71)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:53)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:88)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                          at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:83)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:71)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:53)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:88)
02-28 04:37:53.299 11467-11467/? E/a:     at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:71)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:53)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:88)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                          at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:83)
02-28 04:37:53.299 11467-11467/? E/a:     at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                          at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:83)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:71)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:53)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:88)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                          at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:83)
                                          at com.sample.android.Applicationsample.attachBaseContext(SourceFile:108)
                                          at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:189)
02-28 04:37:53.300 11467-11467/? E/a:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1008)
                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992)
                                          at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:796)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5377)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                      java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Could not generate secret key
                                          at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(SecretKeyFactory.java:474)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:67)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:53)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:88)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                          at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:83)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:71)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:53)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:88)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
02-28 04:37:53.304 11467-11467/? E/a:     at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                          at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:83)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:71)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:53)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:88)
                                          at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                          at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                          at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:32)
                                          at com.sample.android.Applicationsample.attachBaseContext(SourceFile:108)
                                          at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:189)
                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1008)
                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992)
                                          at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:796)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5377)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: invalid UTF-16 codepoint
                                          at com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.Strings.toUTF8ByteArray(Strings.java:177)
                                          at com.android.org.bouncycastle.util.Strings.toUTF8ByteArray(Strings.java:132)
                                          at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS5PasswordToUTF8Bytes(PBEParametersGenerator.java:135)
                                          at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.PBE$Util.convertPassword(PBE.java:438)
                                          at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.PBE$Util.makePBEMacParameters(PBE.java:349)
                                          at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.digest.SHA1$BasePBKDF2WithHmacSHA1.engineGenerateSecret(SHA1.java:141)
                                          at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(SecretKeyFactory.java:463)
                                            ... 826 more
02-28 04:37:53.324 11467-11467/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                   --------- beginning of crash
02-28 04:37:53.331 11467-11467/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.sample.android, PID: 11467
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.sample.android.Applicationsample: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:802)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5377)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                       at android.util.Base64.encode(Base64.java:494)
                                                       at android.util.Base64.encodeToString(Base64.java:456)
                                                       at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:87)
                                                       at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                                       at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
                                                       at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                                       at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:83)
                                                       at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:88)
                                                       at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                                       at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
                                                       at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                                       at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:83)
                                                       at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:71)
                                                       at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:53)
                                                       at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:88)
                                                       at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                                       at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
                                                       at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                                       at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:32)
                                                       at com.sample.android.Applicationsample.attachBaseContext(SourceFile:108)
                                                       at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:189)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1008)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992)
                                                       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:796)
                                                        ... 9 more
02-28 04:37:53.349 11467-11467/? D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 04:37:53.349 11467-11467/? D/Error: ERR: exMsg=Attempt to get length of null array
02-28 04:37:53.349 11467-11467/? D/Error: ERR: file=Base64.java
02-28 04:37:53.349 11467-11467/? D/Error: ERR: class=android.util.Base64
02-28 04:37:53.349 11467-11467/? D/Error: ERR: method=encode line=494
02-28 04:37:53.349 11467-11467/? D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.sample.android.Applicationsample: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                              at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:802)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5377)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                              at android.util.Base64.encode(Base64.java:494)
                                              at android.util.Base64.encodeToString(Base64.java:456)
                                              at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:87)
                                              at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                              at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
                                              at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                              at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:83)
                                              at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:71)
                                              at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:53)
                                              at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                              at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
                                              at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                              at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:83)
                                              at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:71)
                                              at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:53)
                                              at com.sample.android.database.a.a(SourceFile:88)
                                              at com.sample.android.e.c.n(SourceFile:1110)
                                              at com.sample.android.e.c.b(SourceFile:1105)
                                              at com.sample.android.database.a.a.c.a(SourceFile:52)
                                              at com.sample.android.c.a.a(SourceFile:83)
                                            at c
02-28 04:37:53.349 11467-11467/? D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 41256
02-28 04:37:53.350 902-20335/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.sample.android/.activities.Activitysample
```

Below is the proguard file - "proguard-rules.pro" -

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application

-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-dontwarn android.app.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn android.view.**
-dontwarn android.widget.**

-dontwarn com.google.common.primitives.**

-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycombMR2
-dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keep class net.sqlcipher.** {
    *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated, SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keep public class javax.crypto.spec.** {
  public protected *;
}

# Class names are needed in reflection
-keepnames class com.amazonaws.**
# Request handlers defined in request.handlers
-keep class com.amazonaws.services.**.*Handler
# The following are referenced but aren't required to run
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
# Android 6.0 release removes support for the Apache HTTP client
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
# The SDK has several references of Apache HTTP client
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.http.**
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.metrics.**

    enter code here
```

Comment: And this is happening on Android N 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

add these lines in your Proguard file

```
#### -- Sql Cipher --
-keep  class net.sqlcipher.** {
    *;
}

-keep  class net.sqlcipher.database.** {
    *;
}
```